# Iterate over json response and some total bill using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to sum all the total bills in order list in typescript but its not working it says Object is of type 'unknown'. When i am trying to access the total bill. Its working fine in browser console but on Visual code its throwing error.

Here is my json response

```
{
    "order_list": {
       
            "32212000000037": {
                "invoice_id": "32212000000037",
                "customer_id": "006019000015",
                "customer_name": "Spantik",
                "inv_date": "2020-12-24",
                "prod_date": "2020-12-24",
                "inv_time": "09:00",
                "total_bill": 22,
                "notification": "waiting",
                "sales_id": "",
                "inv_type": "regular",
                "danger": "over"
            },
            "32212000000036": {
                "invoice_id": "32212000000036",
                "customer_id": "006019000015",
                "customer_name": "Spantik",
                "inv_date": "2020-12-24",
                "prod_date": "2020-12-24",
                "inv_time": "14:57",
                "total_bill": 22,
                "notification": "waiting",
                "sales_id": "",
                "inv_type": "regular",
                "danger": "over"
            }        
    },
}
```

Here is what I am trying

```js
countTotalBill(orderDate: string) {
  let totalBill = 0;

  const itemList = this.orderLists[orderDate];

  if (itemList != null) {
    const arr = Object.values(itemList);

    arr.filter(ele => {
      totalBill = totalBill + ele.total_bill; // <<<<<<======= here is the problem
    });
  }

  return totalBill;
}
```

Comment: `filter` should return a value. You could use `forEach` instead.

Comment: What are you filtering?

Comment: i  just want to get the value of total_bill

Comment: tried with foreach the same error Object is of type 'unknown'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reduce instead of filter,

```
totalBill = arr.reduce((acc,cur)=>acc + cur.total_bill,0)
```

With Types:

```
const apiResp = {
    order_list: {
        "32212000000037": {
            invoice_id: "32212000000037",
            customer_id: "006019000015",
            customer_name: "Spantik",
            inv_date: "2020-12-24",
            prod_date: "2020-12-24",
            inv_time: "09:00",
            total_bill: 22,
            notification: "waiting",
            sales_id: "",
            inv_type: "regular",
            danger: "over",
        }
    },
};

interface OrderItem {
    [key:string]:string|number;
    total_bill: number;
}

const arr:OrderItem[] = Object.keys(apiResp).map(x=>apiResp[x])

console.log(arr.reduce((acc,cur)=>acc + cur.total_bill,0))
```